# Как узнать название сервера и ссылку на сервер в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я хочу чтобы при бане человеку отправлялось сообщение "Тебя забанили на сервере {server} по причине {reason}" Тоже самое и с разбаном "Тебя разбанили на сервере {server}! {link}"

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} **забанен** \n Продолжительность бана: *{time}d* \n Причина бана: *{reason}*')
  await member.send(f'Тебя забанили на сервере {server} по причине {reason}')
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  await asyncio.sleep(time * 86400)
  await member.unban()
  await ctx.send(f'*У {member.mention} закончился бан*')
  await member.send(f'Тебя разбанили на сервере {server}! {link}')
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} **забанен** \n Продолжительность бана: *{time}d* \n Причина бана: *{reason}*')
  await member.send(f'Тебя забанили на сервере {ctx.guild.name} по причине {reason}')
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  await asyncio.sleep(time * 86400)
  await member.unban()
  await ctx.send(f'*У {member.mention} закончился бан*')
  link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=300)
  await member.send(f'Тебя разбанили на сервере {ctx.guild.name}! {link}')
```